# Mail is not sending in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have followed one tutorial to send mail from php.

```
 public function send_credentials($beneficiary_user){

  $this->load->library(‘email’);
  $email_config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'app123testing@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'apptesting',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n"
    );
    $this->email->from('app123testing@gmail.com', 'invoice');
    $this->email->to('anilapu@navaratan.com');
    $this->email->subject('Invoice');
    $this->email->message('Test');

    $this->email->send();

}
```

*What are the other settings i have to do to make it working*
*After running echo $this->email->print_debugger();. I got*

> Unable to send email using PHP mail().  Your server might not be configured to send mail   using this method.
>
> ```
> User-Agent: CodeIgniter
>      Date: Sun, 9 Feb 2014 14:58:44 +0530
>      From: "invoice" 
>      Return-Path: 
>      Reply-To: "app123testing@gmail.com" 
>      X-Sender: app123testing@gmail.com
>      X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
>      X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
>      Message-ID: <52f74a4c41e32@gmail.com>
>      Mime-Version: 1.0
>      Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_52f74a4c41e88"
>       =?utf-8?Q?Invoice?=
>       This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>       Your email application may not support this format.
>      --B_ALT_52f74a4c41e88
>      Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>      Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>      Test
>      --B_ALT_52f74a4c41e88
>      Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>      Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>     Test
>     --B_ALT_52f74a4c41e88--
> ```

Comment: Can you describe the errors you are getting, both to console and in your error log

Comment: You're not doing anything with your `$email_config` array. You should pass it to the email lib when you are instantiating it.

Comment: call `$this->email->initialize($config);` to initialize the config variables you have set, or passing it in the constructor works as well `$this->load->library('email', $config);`

Comment: Good catch @RainFromHeaven. Completely missed that.

Comment: But i am unable to understand.Where i have to use $this->load->library('email', $config);.Can you give proper directions. I am new to php. i don't how to make it working. @RainFromHeaven

Comment: @AndrewBrown It should be `$this->email->initialize($email_config);` and `$this->load->library('email', $email_config);`

Comment: @RainFromHeaven You should write the reply so we can upvote!

Comment: Thank you. I added $this->email->initialize($email_config);
 $this->load->library('email', $email_config);. Even though iam unable to send mail.

Comment: Not BOTH! See RainFromHeavens answer.

Comment: I tried that one also.But mail is not sending

Comment: After you try to send the email, run this code: `echo $this->email->print_debugger()` and tell us what it returns.

Comment: After running sudo apt-get install postfix fixed my problem

Comment: Doesn't look like your config is set right. It should not be using the php mail function if using SMTP. See source here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Email.php#L1795

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since we found the answer to your issue in the comments, it seemed prudent to write up an answer.

The problem was that your weren't doing anything with your email configuration array (`$email_config`). While you may or may not have had the right settings defined there, they meant nothing as they were not used properly.

Thus, at the very least, you must change your code to reflect the following changes:

```
$email_config = Array(
    'protocol'  => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => '465',
    'smtp_user' => 'app123testing@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'apptesting',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'starttls'  => true,
    'newline'   => "\r\n"
);

$this->load->library('email', $email_config);
```

Please note that this will merely fix the issue with your approach, I cannot verify the credibility of your settings/access credentials.

EDIT:

As per jtheman's suggestion I decided to dig a bit deeper. You may want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17274496/2788532.

EDIT #2:

You can access useful error messages from CI's email class by using the following code (after you attempt to send an email, of course):

```
<?php echo $this->email->print_debugger(); ?>
```

Comment: Correct! Other approaches might be: 1. trying smtp.gmail.com, 2. Port 587, 3. Check your firewall etc

Comment: I tried this already.But i don't know where i am making mistake

Comment: Where i have to place this.Because when i place it in send_credentials it disables remaining code @RainFromHeaven

Comment: Can you see the result of echo $this->email->print_debugger();.I have added to my question @RainFromHeaven

Comment: I defined send_credentials in beneficiaries controller.Did i use email.php

Comment: After running sudo apt-get install postfix. I can able to send email. Thank you for your response @RainFromHeaven.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this in start of the function where you are writing send email code

```
$config = Array(
          'protocol' => 'sendmail',
          'mailtype' => 'html', 
          'charset' => 'utf-8',
          'wordwrap' => TRUE

      );
     $this->email->initialize($config);
```

Email will forward but error same error will show

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

1. Open system/libraries/email.php
2. Edit

   var $newline = "\n";
   var $crlf = "\n";

   to

   var $newline = "\r\n";
   var $crlf = "\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

make changes like this

```
'smtp_crypto'=>'ssl', //add this one
 'protocol' => 'smtp',
 'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 'smtp_port' => 465,
```