# Codeigniter send email not received

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send mail from localhost(LAMP) using codeigniter using the following code snippet. It shows "**Email sent.**". But the email is not received at my email address.

```
function sendMail() {
    $config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // change it to yours
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap'  => TRUE
    );

    $message = '';
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
    $this->email->to('xxx@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
    $this->email->subject('testing');
    $this->email->message($message);
    if($this->email->send()) {
        echo 'Email sent.';
    }
    else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this line: 'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com'. The SSL protocol doesn't sound right. Try SMTP

Comment: I try this 'smtp_host' => 'smtp://smtp.googlemail.com'. but not working

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17274496  Try `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` instead.  Also, have you checked your "spam" folder?

Comment: @ajtrichards: `ssl://smtp.googlemail.com` is actually correct.

Comment: I done some configuration  using postfix http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html

Comment: @mridul try **$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";**

Answer (score 3):

change,
`'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',`
To
`$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";`

Answer (score 0):

I  had the same issue ,  I switched to  Free Email emgine Mail[enter link description here](https://mailtrap.io/)trap  which is free  -  and it doesnt flood  our inbox  will all test email , all  you need to do is  just sign up  and use its smtp Details .

I have lib you want  to use its [api](https://github.com/jaiwalker/mailtrap)

Answer (score 0):

In my case on protocols mail/sendmail/tls working without any error in a server with CodeIgniter but I didn't get mail and no error. How would I know what's the problem and in case of smtp protocols it gave an error.